# Which character is best for killing Bastion from behind Reinhardt?

Tags: overwatch

Often, at the start of a game, the defense has a Bastion set up in sentry mode near the objective, aimed at a chokepoint. When this happens, one of the best strategies is to have a Reinhardt stand in front of Bastion with his barrier up, and have someone or someones shoot the Bastion from behind the barrier. Obviously it would be best to have the whole team shoot it, but this can be hard to organize in a random lobby.

**Which character can kill the Bastion fastest in this situation?** Can they kill it before the barrier goes down?

Assume:

- The Bastion is reasonably far away. Say 20-40m.
- The person shooting is fairly skilled, but not an aimbot. Hitting the Bastion with every shot from Fan the Hammer is not realistic.
- There is only one person behind Reinhardt shooting, not the whole team.

*Bonus:* What other characters can kill the Bastion before the barrier goes down, as the only shooter?

Comment: Uh, Bastion can melt a Reinhardt's shield without even having to reload, so you probably want to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @Powerlord This has worked plenty of times for me in-game. There's usually more than one person shooting, though.

Comment: @Powerlord Time that Bastion spends on melting Reinhardt's barrier is time spent vulnerable to anyone shooting from behind the barrier.

Comment: @Powerlord The question takes into account that the shield goes down. The question is about killing the Bastion in that time frame. If you think that no hero can do that, then that's a valid answer.

Comment: @Yuuki It takes, what, 1 second for Bastion to destroy the shield?  It's absurdly short.

Comment: @Powerlord In practical situations, Bastion usually takes a moment to notice and start firing. The specific length of time it takes Bastion to destroy a barrier would be a good fact to include in an answer.

Comment: @Powerlord Bastion's Sentry Mode does a maximum of 525 damage per second. This is at close range, not the 20-40m the asker specifies. Even with this optimal damage, Reinhardt's Barrier is 2000 health. It takes *much* longer than 1 second for Bastion to destroy Reinhardt's Barrier. The reason why you probably experience smaller times is that the enemy team is focusing Reinhardt's Barrier.

Comment: @Yuuki Not all weapons in Overwatch have damage falloff.  A lot of them simply have lower accuracy at a distance, but that wouldn't affect Reinhardt's shield because it's such a huge target.

Comment: @Powerlord Bastion's Sentry Mode does have damage falloff. It ranges from 4-15 damage per bullet.

Comment: You can [watch this, F**k bastion, The Gentlemans Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grjaqS87eoo) by Muselk

Comment: Whats the reason for a teammate shooting the bastion? To me its not quiet clear what you are asking. also even if it isn't a random lobby you shouldn't set up a whole team jsut to take out a duo in enemys team.

Comment: The real question should be: What to do against Bastion when it's behind the shield. Killing an unshielded bastion takes only a couple of peeks around the corner with Hanzo, Pharah, McCree etc., given that you are not its only target.

Comment: @NumLock There are a few things that pass through Reinhardt's shield, like Symmetra's charged shot and Reinhardt's E skill. You can use these to poke/kill people behind his shield.

Comment: Another way of doing it, if the enemy team is absent/occupied is simply to have a Reaper shadowstep in behind Bastion and unload both shotguns into him. At worst, Bastion has to turn or transform out, Reaper dies but the pressure is relieved enough to get some damage out. At best, Bastion goes down and Reaper can turn his/her attention to someone else from behind their line and distract them for you to push out.

Comment: Mei's Ice Wall between the choke point and Bastion may also be a decent way to prevent Bastion from focusing into a group as well, by forcing him to split his fire left and right of the wall you can get people out and flank/focus him down.

Comment: @sequoiad Bastion generally just shoots through the wall.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bastion fires 35 bullets per second which deal 15 HP damage per each in a close combat, which translates into 525 damage per second. This means Bastion alone will melt the shield in approx. 3.8 seconds at an ideal situation. (My information may not be accurate, however. If that is the case, then just modify the numbers written here.)

However, the real situation is not that ideal. On our plus side, Bastion has damage dropoff which degrades their absurdly high damage output at a range, but the bad news is that Bastion probably has friends around them. I'll assume one standard hero such as McCree or Soldier: 76 would be around them, who has less damage output than Bastion but a significant threat against that gargantuan shield, anyway.

Thus, assuming that Reinhardt's shield lowers after three seconds, these are the heroes who satisfy the DPS bar:

- **Pharah**. Her rocket deals 120 damage at a direct hit and fires slightly faster than 1 round per second. Passes the damage check by taking less than 2 seconds (from the first rocket fire) for destroying Bastion.
- **Bastion** themself. Even without math, it is obvious that taking down an enemy Bastion would take less time than breaking Reinhardt's shield. Do note, however, that the offending Bastion might require a delay (which is one second) before stapling themself into the Sentry mode. They could consider installing themself onto a moving object beforehand (e. g. the Payload), or perform the mode switch while falling from a ledge to minimize the effective delay.
- **Junkrat**, if he can directly hit the target. Same damage as Pharah, with slightly faster fire rate. Note that, however, using him exclusively for this scenario is not an optimal strategy because of his trajectory.
- **Hanzo**. Each fully charged arrow deals 125 damage, and takes slightly more than 1 second to fully charge and fire. Thus, surprisingly, Hanzo can also pass the damage check when the enemy counterattack is thin aside from Bastion's.

Bonus point for **Mercy** amping anyone mentioned here, or **Zenyatta** attaching an *Orb of Discord*.

Special cases worth a remark:

- **Roadhog** actually has no means of getting through the DPS bar via shots. However, a test from the training room revealed that he can *Chain Hook* an enemy as far away as 20 metres, which means he can pull back Bastion safely if they are close enough. Although *Hook*ing alone has minimal impact on Bastion's health, **it forces them out of *Configuration: Sentry***, and pulls them into the close quarter where Reinhardt and Roadhog can shred them with maximum efficiency. Worth noting if your team is close enough.

Comment: Best answer so far due to the presence of math. Did you base the three seconds on anything in particular? Seems like a reasonable figure, just wondering.

Comment: @DCShannon Bastion takes 3~4+ seconds to take down the shield at that distance. However, they will not be alone, so I added a standard hero such as McCree or Soldier: 76 near their existence, hence the three-second assumption.

Comment: Using Bastion + Reinhardt to counter Bastion doesn't require a moving object. If you know there is a Bastion beforehand, you can jump and then shift as Bastion to gain some ground, even more if it's off a ledge or something, and have the Reinhardt reveal at the same time. Additionally, it's a bad assumption to assume Bastion can melt another before the shield drops. Bastion has 100 armor, which reduces damage by half up to a max of 5 damage per instance of damage. Since Bastion fires a lot of bullets for small damage and has damage falloff ((20-10.5 damage at 20-40m))the math may not check out

Comment: @RFKomos Bastion's health consists of 100 armor and 200 plain, which nets into 300. Even in the worst case when each bullet's damage is halved by the armor, the effective health still nets at 400. Considering a healer nearby or failing to acquire the target is an entirely different story, but in that case any character will lose anyway. Removing emphasis for mobility would be a good thing, though, so I guess I'll modify that part.

Comment: You forgot RoadHog, the grab will force bastion out of it's sentry mode, and the shotgun + reinhardt's hammer will chop bastion to pieces

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I just tested out in the training room. I was actually surprised when I found out I could *Chain Hook* an opponent **20 metres** far away from Roadhog. However, the scenario requires anywhere from 20 metres to 40 metres, and from 25 metres (I guess), unfortunately, he couldn't pull a training bot. Guess I could make a special remark there, though.

Comment: [Source for edited damage values](http://owinfinity.com/en/hero/bastion/). Also of note that at 20m, Bastion's damage is affected by drop-off. I can test exactly how much when I get an opportunity, but I believe at 20m it starts dropping off at 1pt per 2m, meaning his damage is at the lowest threshold after 42m. Shouldn't be *too* hard to test, right?

Comment: I'm not sure they technically meet the criteria, but in maps where there's an alternate route around the chokepoint, getting a Mei or Tracer in behind the Bastion often results in a scrap heap. Mei freezes the Bastion then puts an icicle or two into him, and Tracer just moves faster than he can track at near-point-blank range.

Answer (score 15):

Pharah can kill a Bastion with three direct rockets at any range (doesn't even need the Reinhardt if she peeks around a corner!), Widowmaker can do the same with three fully charged shots, and Zenyatta can kill a Bastion in 5 normal shots if he uses his Orb of Discord beforehand.

These are probably the three fastest kills, and they work at any range thanks to their lack of damage fall off, and their lack of spread and projectile drop.

Comment: I would think Hanzo would have a similar time to kill compared to Widowmaker?

Comment: @DCShannon He would, but I decided to list the three best and easiest heroes for the job. The falloff on Hanzo's arrows, although minimal, still makes him harder than Widowmaker.

Comment: Zenyatta can also combo the Orb of Discord with one full charge shot to take out Bastion, which may be more ideal in some circumstances.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Actually, he can't. He needs 5 normal shots, not the full charge. Each orb fired by the full charge is weaker than individual ones.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I've done it, multiple times.  So unless they've shadow-patched it...  Looking at the math on it, it shouldn't work - but I have done it.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck That wasn't from full health, then. It's been that way for as long as Zenyatta has been in the game, AFAIK.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer As I said, it was from full health.  Which is odd, given that the math doesn't appear to track.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Excluding attacking its weak point, which is not possible from the front, you can't kill a full health Bastion with an Orb of Discord and a fully charged alt fire. I'm as confused as you.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm mostly recalling flanking attacks, so it is possible I managed to tag that.  In any case, 1 charge and 1 normal is still less exposure, and thus safer, so it's a useful note.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Exposition doesn't matter since this question is about attacking from behind Reinhardt's shield.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer In the interest of a more complete answer, however, it is important to point out how the tactics can adapt as the situation changes.  After all, you'll almost never see such a clean and controlled circumstance in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever I run into a Bastion + Reinhardt setup, I switch to Symmetra. (And the situation you mention is a subset of this)

There are a few good reasons for this:

- Symmtra's Alt-Fire travels *through* enemy barriers like Reinhardt's shield, and can deal 125 damage when fully charged (2 seconds). This will kill Bastion in 3 shots. (Assuming no additional healing)
- In addition to the previous point, the Alt-Fire will travel through *players* as well. It's fully possible to hit Reinhardt's shield, Reinhardt himself, *and* Bastion if they're all lined up.
- The Alt-Fire is normally hard to hit with because it travels so slowly, but if Bastion is in Turret mode, he can't dodge. And if he leaves Turret mode to avoid your projectiles, you've succeeded at your objective.
- The Alt-Fire doesn't require LOS to charge up; you should line up your shot, duck into cover, then repeatedly charge, duck into sight, fire, and then return to cover while starting to charge up another shot. Repeat liberally.
- Symmetra has shields, so even if Bastion damages her while peeking out, she can simple wait another few seconds to recover from all her damage.

If you're able to ignore the barrier, the Bastion + Reinhardt combo loses a lot of its potency, since both heroes are relying heavily on the barrier to survive -- their entire gameplan is to have Bastion kill your team before your team breaks the barrier. As soon as one or both of them crumble, you've succeeded.

Against a lone Bastion, this strategy is just as good -- without a barrier or healer to back him up, the slow-moving photon balls can often force a Bastion to move -- which resolves the problem all the same.

Comment: While definitely helpful, I think the asker is asking who can best use Reinhardt as cover to take out a Bastion quickly rather than how to beat a Reinhardt + Bastion combo.

Comment: Bastion is not behind a Reinhardt. The shooter is behind Reinhardt.

Comment: @Yuuki Fair point, but I'd still wager the answer is the same. -- Don't bother with Reinhardt, use Symmetra

Comment: This strategy sounds like it could still work if you're behind a friendly Reinhardt.

Comment: I agree to this strategy as a symmetra main , my top one counter to a shielded Bastion is Symmetra's orbs

Answer (score 2):

I'd say widow is your best option: 3 shot with widow, but after first shot bastion can be reactive and try to run out because he know that if he wait 2sd shot to go back to recon form (which take 1 second (0.5 to go sentry)) you'll have charge the 3rd hit.

To rephrase, bastion HAS to recon once a widow shot him once, or his dead (same go with phara and hanzo) but if he do so he can survive, (especially if he placed himself next to a wall). So if he recon after first shot you need the headshot. It's really easy to headshot Bastion from long distance with widow because of his big head and slow movements. With hanzo it would be a little harder if distance is really big. And phara... well headshot, you know..

So definitely, for me widow is the best option to kill bastion -> 3 shot if he don't recon, 2 shot if he recon and you get the head. You don't even need a reinhardt if you have a wall you can hide behind after each shot, you kill him first, but even behind reinhardt I don't see a better option.

EDIT:

Remember that bastion shot 30 bullet doing 15 damage each second so 450 damage per second, reinhardt shield has 2000 hp, it will take about 4.4 sec to destroy reinhardt shield, if they have a second bastion or phara or something doing huge damage to reinhardt shield, it won't last enought time for you do destroy it, or even if you kill him, reinhardt won't have more that 650 hp (assuming only one person try to kill bastion, it will take 3 second, for widow phara and hanzo) So you'll be in a bad position even after killing one of them. So you'd better kill it with widow or make him go back with phara or hanzo without reinhardt but hidding behind a wall after each shot, so you save reinhardt shield.

Assuming you really want to be behind a reinhardt, I think (sorry for mistaking earlier) you'd better go for a bastion which will destroy him in 1.2 sec ( 0.7 sec of damage + 0.5 sec to get in sentry) so here you save your reinhardt shield at at least 1400 hp. You can even forget about the 0.5 sec to get in sentry because you can do it while jumping and reinhardt can shield you once you are in sentry mode (assuming you won't die in a jump of 0.5 sec getting sentry, since bastion need about 0.7 sec to damage you enought + you have some movement). So behind a reinhardt, Bastion is the best because you NEED TO think about your reinhardt shields hp. Still you'll have to attack with a bastion after that, I still think widow without reinhardt shield's is the best option.

Answer (score -1):

I main Genji and recently found a decent tactic if the Bastion and rein are fairly isolated (usually happens since if he's at the front line, Rein can't risk lowering shield to recharge). I first find some height advantage over the bastion so he doesn't immediately notice you as he focuses on your team, then I literally dive through the reinhardt shield with the dash, and deflect right after. What happens next depends on whether the Bastion panic fires at you. If he does, which usually happens because the Bastion knows he's buying minutes of time by being set up, he'll eliminate himself. Don't try to take out the rein after, just dash and run. If he doesn't panic fire, you're probably dead (start running while your deflect is still up). However, your team should immediately take the opportunity to rush in since their main defensive formation is down; ideally someone will eliminate the now out of position Bastion and send him back to spawn.

First did this on temple of Anubis and eliminated a bastion within seconds of noticing he was there. Climbed up on the main arch, dashed down, told the team to push hard, and deflected into the Bastion.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is asking for someone who can do it from behind Reinhardt's shield, not how to kill a Bastion that is hiding behind Reinhardt's shield.

Answer (score -1):

My pick would be genji or roadhog because roadhog can hook bastion out of his sentry form and genji can deflect any bullet that are shot and roadhog can heal the damage

Comment: There's not enough detail here to be useful. How is Roadhog supposed to hook the Bastion if there's a Rein shield blocking the way? Same thing with Genji. (Not to mention that any Bastion with half a brain is going to stop shooting at a reflecting Genji almost immediately.)